# How to connect to Neo4j inside Docker with Spring?

Tags: docker, spring-boot, neo4j

I have Neo4j running in Docker container:

```
docker run --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 --name=neo4j -e NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/psswd neo4j:latest
```

I can access Neo4j with this URL: `http://localhost:7474/browser/`.

And also I can connect to Neo4j with Spring outside Docker with this URI: `bolt://localhost:7687/mydb`.

But when I try to connect to Neo4j with Spring inside Docker with another URI `bolt://neo4j:7687/mydb`:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -t myapp --link neo4j:neo4j
```

I get the exception:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: neo4j

And when I try the same with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, I get the exception:

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

What URI should I use? And what am I doing wrong?

Neo4j logs look like this:

```
======== Neo4j 3.3.4 ========
Starting...
Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
Started.
Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
```

Comment: Have you tried to work with a `user-defined` bridge network?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried running both containers with `--network=mynetwork" and it works.

Comment: Glad it worked out! I've posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `user-defined` bridge network, so that you have DNS resolution between containers.

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge):

> - **User-defined bridges provide automatic DNS resolution between containers.**
>
>   Containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by IP addresses, unless you use the `--link` option, which is considered legacy. On a user-defined bridge network, containers can resolve each other by name or alias.

---

*And when I try the same with localhost or 127.0.0.1, I get the exception...*

When you are inside a container and try to access "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" you are referring to the container itself, not the host.